# SmartGWT Not working with Maven and Jetty Chrome Ubuntu x64

Tags: java, gwt, maven, smartgwt

I am trying to create a GWT project using Maven and SmartGWT. The GWT module I made worked fines so I tried creating the following EntryPoint for SmartGWT.

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();  
    form.setWidth(500);  
    form.setNumCols(4);  

    ComboBoxItem bugStatusItem = new ComboBoxItem("bugStatus");  
    bugStatusItem.setTitle("Bug Status");  

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> valueMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();  
    valueMap.put("new", "New");  
    valueMap.put("active", "Active");  
    valueMap.put("revisit", "Revisit");  
    valueMap.put("fixed", "Fixed");  
    valueMap.put("delivered", "Delivered");  
    valueMap.put("resolved", "Resolved");  
    valueMap.put("reopened", "Reopened");  

    bugStatusItem.setValueMap(valueMap);  
    form.setItems(bugStatusItem);  

    form.draw(); 
}
```

But when I open up in Chrome (using ubuntu x64) I see the following...

http://127.0.0.1:8888/Header.html:

```
GWT module 'com.gleason.ecommerce.textmanagement.gwt.Header' may need to be (re)compiled
```

http://127.0.0.1:8888/Header.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

```
00:19:55.205 [ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class 
com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint (see associated exception for details)    
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Browser' of undefined at    
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136) at     
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107) at 
com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint.init(SmartGwtEntryPoint.java) at 
com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(SmartGwtEntryPoint.java:239) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have tried a gwt:compile, that didn't help.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: I have the mvn dependecy:tree but it keeps failing when I try to post

Comment: the first link you've provided is used to run the project in compile mode & the 2nd link to run the project in developement mode. You should not be getting the 1st exception when you run the project using 2nd link. right?

Comment: That is correct, Also what I did not make abundantly clear is that if I use a regular GWT entry point (no SmarGWT classes) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is NOT the best solution here is what I came up with.

The problem (if you ask smartGWT) is a bug in GWT. This has something to do with the way the GWT classes are compiled. The essential answer is SmartGWT cannot be used with the maven gwt plugin. One can get around this but a "mvn clean compile gwt:compile package" and deploying the created jar to a tomcat server.

I wish there was a cleaner solution but this worked for me.